# pstricks with "colorfunction" in a tikz loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, pstricks

Trying to make a spiral of vectors (rotating arrow as a function of x-position) I came across tikz for making a proper loop. Concerning other loop solutions I had problems to apply more complicated functions on the loop parameter to calculate the angle of the vectors (the example below only uses `sin` and `cos` but I am using `atan` etc.). In a next step I wanted to color the arrows as a function of a parameter. My intermediate solution is from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128598/double-foreach-for-color-shifting-nodes). What I actually want is to define the rgb-color with some complex function of the loop parameter. As a non-working example, something like this

```
%NON WORKING "WISHLIST"  
\foreach \x in {-15,...,15} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\myRed{\x + 0.5*sin(\x)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\myGreen{\x - 0.5*cos(\x)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\myBlue{\x - 0.5*atan(\x)}
    \newrgbcolor{varCol}{\myRed \myGreen \myBlue}
    \psline[linecolor=varCol]{->}(\xx,0)(0,\xx)
}
```

I looked at more complex examples like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194219/how-to-iterate-a-list-of-colors-with-two-additional-counters-more-elegantly), but I cannot figure out how to adapt this to my problem. Is there a way to implement the idea of the above non-working code to run in the below working example?

(MikTeX 2.9 (32-Bit) Portable, Win7 64-Bit)

```
%NOT SATISFYING WORKAROUND FOR THE MOMENT
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}%{article}
%\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-8,0)(8.0,10)

\foreach \x in {-15,...,15} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\angle{\x*\x*\x/125 * 25.01}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xx{\x + 0.5*sin(\angle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\XX{\x - 0.5*sin(\angle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\yy{6+0.5*cos(\angle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\YY{6-0.5*cos(\angle)}

    %\pgfmathsetmacro\myRed{0.5-0.1*cos(\angle)}
    %\newrgbcolor{rgb}{varCol}{0,.5,0}
    %\newrgbcolor{varCol}{.1 \myRed 0}

    %\definecolor{\abcdefg}{rgb}{.2,.3,.4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\myMix{50-50*sin(\angle)}
    \psline[linecolor={red!\myMix!green}, linewidth=2pt]{->}(\xx,\yy)(\XX,\YY)
}   
\end{pspicture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer of Herbert, I played a little more with this problem. Due to the braces he uses in the algebraic option of PSTricks, I tried those in the color definitions. This now works.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-8,0)(8.0,10)
\foreach \x in {-9,...,9} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\angle{\x*\x*\x/125 * 25.01}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xx{.8*\x + 0.5*sin(\angle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\XX{.8*\x - 0.5*sin(\angle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\yy{6+0.5*cos(\angle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\YY{6-0.5*cos(\angle)}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\myRed{ (1 - cos(\angle/2-45 )^2  )^2 }
    \pgfmathsetmacro\myGreen{ (1 - cos(\angle/2+45 )^2 )^2 }
    \pgfmathsetmacro\myBlue{ (cos(\angle/2 )^2 )^2 }
    \newrgbcolor{varCol}{{\myRed} {\myGreen} {\myBlue}}

    \psline[linecolor=varCol, linewidth=2pt]{->}(\xx,\yy)(\XX,\YY)
}   
\end{pspicture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

providing this output
[image]

The only trick was, hence, the braces on the color name inside the `\newrgbcolor`.

Also note that I did not use the algebraic option of coordinates in PSTricks here. When I tried to calculate the coordinate inside the position argument of the according PSTricks function, it first gave me a different result. The reason is, I believe, that trigonometric functions in `tikz` take angels in degrees, while trigonometric functions within the algebraic option of coordinates in PSTricks take angles in radiant. Surely, this is an easy change, but I am just too lazy.

Answer (score 2):

use the algebraic option of coordinates in PSTricks:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-16,5)(8.0,7)
\pgfforeach \x in {-15,...,15} {%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\angle{\x*\x*\x/125 * 25.01}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\myMix{50-50*sin(\angle)}
    \psline[linecolor={red!\myMix!green}, linewidth=2pt]{->}%
      (+{\x+sin(\angle)/2, 6+cos(\angle)/2})%
      (+{\x-sin(\angle)/2, 6-cos(\angle)/2})
}   
\end{pspicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry if my question has been somewhat unclear. While this is a nice improvement which I will certainly use, my main point is independently to define the red, green, and blue values of the `linecolor` for each `x ` and not only to mix two given colors. I want, hence, to provide a far more complex color function `myCol(x)`

Comment: Although, not exactly the answer to my problem, it helped me to solve it; thanks. Cheers.